# batch xcopy only files larger than a certain size

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

Have to extract from a recovered 4TB HDD some files

to extract jpg files I'm using the following script:

```
@echo off
cd /d "f:\old"
for /d %%a in (*.*) do xcopy /y "%%a\*.jpg" "F:\jpg\"
```

but.. if I would copy only files larger than 100 KB.. what shall I add to the script?

sorry if question is too easy but my knowledge of batch script is practically zero.

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
pushd "f:\old"
for /d %%a in (*.*) do (if %%~zF geq 102400 (xcopy /y "%%F" "F:\jpg\"))
```

This will copy all files which are "Greater than or equal (>=)" 100KB.

Comment: You forgot to include the critical FOR /D part of the command

Comment: Why GOTO :BREAK? All that does is exit the loop prematurely and "break" your code.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for answer... but.. is not working.. seems does not execute it

:-(

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@echo off
cd /d "f:\old"
for /d %%a in (*.*) do if %%~za geq 102400 (xcopy /y "%%a\*.jpg" "F:\jpg\")
```

We can get size of the file by `%%~z{your_variable}`