# .bat file to xcopy files of greater than certain size

Tags: batch-file

I have this code in a .bat file which works ok, except I want to only copy files greater than 50 KB.

```
cd "C:\Users\Public\Documents\NTLogFiles"
Xcopy "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\NinjaTrader 8\log\log.????????.0000?.en.txt" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\NTLogFiles\log.????????.txt" /A /D /Y
```

I'm trying to work with this, which is not getting it done.

```
cd "C:\Users\Public\Documents\NTLogFiles"
for %%a in (log*.txt) do if %%za geo 50000 (Xcopy /p /a /d /y %%~za "C:\Users\Public\Documents\NTLogFiles\log.????????.txt")
```

I finally settled on using robocopy to get the files I wanted by size and then using xcopy to move them to their final destination while getting them renamed.

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\NinjaTrader 8\log" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\NTLogFilesTemp" log.*.en.txt /Min:100000
Xcopy "C:\Users\Public\Documents\NTLogFilesTemp\log.????????.0000?.en.txt" "C:\Users\Public\Documents\NTLogFiles\log.????????.txt" /A /D /Y
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [batch xcopy only files larger than a certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101418/batch-xcopy-only-files-larger-than-a-certain-size)

Comment: What about [`robocopy.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html), which supports a `/MIN` option for exactly that purpose?